# RESTFUL web services - client application not linking to web service

Tags: java, rest, request, client, uri

If this has been asked somewhere before, please let me know. The crux of the problem may be similar, I'm not sure.

I basically have two programs on Eclipse. A client and a web service with rest (I'm using REST 3.1.3 by the way). The problem, quite simply, is that my client app is not linking to the restful web service to get the request I'm asking for.

Namely, I'm trying to get a list of author channels from the web service's own database. The problem is not that the service can't retrieve the data itself, rather than that the client can't access the web service to get THAT data from it and then display in its own JSP.

Here is the method from the client app that I'm trying to use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Channel> getAllChannels() {


    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    System.out.println("Client created.");

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/RESTService/examples/channels/authorchannels");
    Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

    List<Channel> channels = null;

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {

        System.out.println("Could not retrieve!" );

    } else {


        channels = (List<Channel>) response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(response.getMediaType().toString());
        System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));

    }

    return channels;

}
```

It belongs to the following interface and class:

class Channel.java:

```
package examples.pubhub.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="channels")
public class Channel implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="channel_user")
private String channel_user;

@Id
@Column(name="channel_bio")
private String channel_bio;

public Channel() {


}

public Channel(String user, String bio) {
    super();
    this.channel_user = user;
    this.channel_bio = bio;

}
```

interface ChannelDAO.java :

```
package examples.pubhub.dao;

import java.util.List;

import examples.pubhub.model.Channel;

public interface ChannelDAO {

public List<Channel> getAllChannels();
public Channel getChannelByAuthorUser(String author_user);
public void createAuthorChannel(String author_user);

}
```

The method would send a get request to the following method in the web service:

AuthorChannel.java (from RESTService):

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("authorchannels")
    public List<Response> getAllChannels() {

    Session session = DAOUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Channel");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> channels = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    ResponseBuilder respBuilder = null;

    if (channels == null)
        respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    else
        respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);

    respBuilder.entity(channels);

    System.out.println("Channels? " + channels);
    System.out.println("Users? " + ((Channel) 
    channels.get(0)).getChannel_user());
    System.out.println("Bios? " + ((Channel) 
    channels.get(0)).getChannel_bio());

    return (List<Response>) respBuilder.build();

    }
```

When I try to test this on Postman, it gives me a 404. I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm thinking the URI might be incorrect, but I'm noticing conflicting theories on how the URI should be written.

My biggest problem is mostly misinformation on this topic; any help would be appreciated. If you want to see anything else from the code, please let me know.

Controller code:

```
package methods;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import model.Channel;
import resources.DAOUtilities;

@Path("/channels")
public class AuthorChannel {


    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void createAuthorChannel(@PathParam("id") String user, @QueryParam("bio") String bio) {

        Session session = DAOUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Channel channel = new Channel();
        channel.setChannel_bio(bio);
        channel.setChannel_user(user);

        session.save(channel);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();


    }

    @GET
    @Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/authorchannels")
    public List<Response> getAllChannels() {

        Session session = DAOUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Channel");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Object> channels = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        ResponseBuilder respBuilder = null;

        if (channels == null)
            respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        else
            respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);

        respBuilder.entity(channels);

        System.out.println("Channels? " + channels);
        System.out.println("Users? " + ((Channel) channels.get(0)).getChannel_user());
        System.out.println("Bios? " + ((Channel) channels.get(0)).getChannel_bio());

        return (List<Response>) respBuilder.build();

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response getChannelByAuthorUser(@PathParam("id") String channel_user) {

        Session session = DAOUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Channel where channel_user = :channel_user");
        query.setParameter("channel_user", channel_user);
        Channel channel = (Channel) query.uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        ResponseBuilder respBuilder = null;

        if (channel == null)
            respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        else
            respBuilder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);

        respBuilder.entity(channel);

        return respBuilder.build();

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the controller path?

Comment: AuthorChannel.java should be @Path("/channels"), or @Path("channels"); not sure which one.

and then the method for getting all the channels should be @Path("/authorchannels")

Comment: Well that may explain the problems. Could you post the controller's code?

Comment: I added the code below, directly under "Controller code:"

Comment: What is the url you are using from the client?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/RESTService/examples/channels/authorchannels

There should be an http:// at the beginning, but stack overflow won't let me see it.

Comment: I think you would need to post your server config. Code is getting long. Try to come up with an [MCVE]

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem.